# Is it right to say "my curiosity was intrigued by that strange symbol"?

Tags: etymology

Technically, it seems wrong as "intrigue" by itself means "to arouse the curiosity or interest of", but I see plenty of articles and books all over the internet with that usage. Please enlighten!

Comment: [No.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=curiosity+was+intrigued&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) It's gibberish to say "my curiosity was intrigued," unless you have a pet cat named Curiosity. Can you cite an example where you've seen this usage? You *can* say "that strange symbol piqued my curiosity."

Comment: All you need to do is google "my curiosity was intrigued"(WITH the quotes obviously). You could find several instances of that usage. I like the cat's example by the way!

Comment: The fact that lots of people use a word incorrectly does not make it correct... A more correct phrase would be 'My curiosity was aroused by the strange symbol', or 'My curiosity was piqued by the strange symbol'

Comment: BadBoy -- google means nothing.  If you google **incorrect spellings of words** you'll find thousands of examples.

Comment: **No**, it's completely incorrect.  You say my curiosity was aroused; or my curiosity was piqued.  Or, simply say "I was intrigued by..."

Comment: Even if it is wrong semantically, alas, usage can provide legitimacy. I can argue that "ask a question" has the same problem as this sentence, but we have gotten all too used to it. (Pose a question or ask something -> mix it up and you are asking a question).

Comment: @JoeBlow I didn't mean to say that Google is always right. Since njboot asked me to cite an example, I was just doing it. I came across that usage in some books as well. Now that intrigued me! I was just trying to get a clarification on the same.

Answer (score 2):

[piqued](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pique) is possibly the word you're looking for.

*pique* (verb)- to cause (curiosity or interest)

eg.

> Her mentioning that she'd once been arrested *piqued* my curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Though less common than 'aroused' (a valid alternative)  I think *intrigued* is acceptable as used in the sentence.

> [to intrigue](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Intrigued):
>
> to arouse the interest or curiosity of: Hibernation has long intrigued biologists.

The usage of *intrigued* and *intriguing* has been increasing during recent decades
[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intrigued,intriguing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,intrigued;,c0;.t1;,intriguing;,c0), see also the note below:

> Usage Note: The introduction of the verb intrigue to mean "to arouse the interest or curiosity of" was initially resisted by writers on usage as an unneeded French substitute for available English words such as interest, fascinate, or puzzle, but it now appears to be well established. Seventy-eight percent of the Usage Panel accepts it in the sentence The special-quota idea intrigues some legislators, who have asked a Washington think tank to evaluate it, whereas only 52 percent accepted it in a 1968 survey.

Source: American Heritage Dictionary.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I deleted it!  I believe you may have misread the question, cheers.

Comment: Josh: how do you arouse the curiosity of your curiosity? I think it is a damn ugly construction - but then again, if enough people use it, it may join the ranks of "I could care less", "irregardless" and "ask a question"...